# Matrix representation of state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

This is  a quantum  mechanics question, I don't quite understand what it's getting at...

> Suppose the we have a state described by $|1\,\,\, m\rangle$. Let its matrix representation be $\vec u$. The angular momentum measured in $(0, \sin\theta, \cos\theta)$ direction is $+1$. What are the components of $\vec u$?

I presume  one starts by assuming a basis $|1\,\,\, 1\rangle, |1\,\,\, 0\rangle, |1\,\,\, -1\rangle$ or something? I have no idea of what's going on...

Comment: joshphysics probably got the right interpretation below but yikes, $\vec{u}$ is a bad notation for a Hilbert space vector (and then calling it a matrix), especially when the question mentions an ordinary 3-vector in the next breath! No wonder you're confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the vector
$$
  \mathbf n = (0, \sin\theta, \cos\theta)
$$
defined in the question is a unit vector.  The operator that corresponds to measuring angular momentum in the direction of this unit vector is
$$
  \mathbf n\cdot \mathbf L
$$
When the question says that the angular momentum measured in the direction of $\mathbf n$ is $+1$, what it is referring to is the state $|u\rangle$ that is an eigenvector of $\mathbf n\cdot\mathbf L$ with eigenvalue $+1$;
$$
  \mathbf n \cdot\mathbf L |u\rangle = |u\rangle
$$
The matrix representation $\vec u = (u^1, u^2, u^3)^t$ (here superscript $t$ means transpose indicating that the matrix representation is a column vector) of this state refers to the matrix representation of $|u\rangle$ in the basis $|1,1\rangle, |1,0\rangle, |1,-1\rangle$;
$$
  \vec u = \Big(\langle 1,1|u\rangle, \langle 1,0|u\rangle, \langle 1,-1|u\rangle\Big)^t
$$

Comment: @Clarice Sure thang!